# when I adding a note in my todo list app i am getting error in console i think the problem is in react

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api

I'm using axios in a React App. This is the code where I make the API call. It throws an error in the console: `Uncaught (in promise) Failed to fetch`

```
const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/updatenote/${id}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": "auth-token"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({title, description, tag})
    });
const json =  response.json();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What error you are getting, Also please use correct formatting for the code and add some more details so that its easier to understand the problem.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that your fetch request has failed. It's not a react issue. Check the endpoint: is it returning data as you expected?

Comment: thank you for replying actually I am new to coding, I am learning, this is my first time asking question on stackoverflow , I am learning a react course from codewithharry youtube channel this is my github file till now https://github.com/PixelshotsDevelopes/todolist-vid65-err-codeWithHarry.git I am  stuck at video 65 where in addstate,js in editnote and addnote function when I am adding note note on front end my console giving me error also I filled the headers hardcore not dynamic according to tut video